# Not found Sql.MigrationSqlGenerator.set_ProviderManifest

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I using entity framework 6 code first and when i'm trying execute **Update-database** command i get message:

> Method not found: 'Void
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Sql.MigrationSqlGenerator.set_ProviderManifest(System.Data.Entity.Core.Common.DbProviderManifest)'.

thanks for any help

Comment: Normally in "Method not found" exceptions, either an assembly is not the same version that is expected. Or the application/Visual Studio needs to be restarted to find the new version of the assemblies.

Comment: I am having the same issue. I have a the final version of EF, and this started occuring after converting from model-first into code-first for me. Restarting didn't help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved it on my end. I was using Entity Framework 6.0.2 (the latest) which apparently has this bug.

Re-installing the package didn't help, but this did:

```
Install-Package EntityFramework -Pre
```

In other words, use the package manager to install the latest beta (6.1) of Entity Framework, and you're good to go. I guess we'll just have to wait until it is stable for the bug to be fixed.